# Populate sections from a grid using javascript function using variables check for each

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I want to populate a grid based on sections, for example section one, section two, section three and so on and I have created a variable for each section in order to be populated with my array with values from 1 to 7 separately.

Now I have created a “function” on which I have added a `for` for each section variable, but after that I don’t know how to run `Array.from` function in order to populate each section with values.

```
    var one = document.querySelectorAll(‘selector section one’);
    var two = document.querySelectorAll(‘selector section two’);
    var three = document.querySelectorAll(‘selector section three’);
    var four = document.querySelectorAll(‘selector section four’);
    var five = document.querySelectorAll(‘selector section five’);
    var six = document.querySelectorAll(‘selector section six’);
    var seven = document.querySelectorAll(‘selector section seven’);

    var bigArr = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven];

    function populate(f){
      for (var i = 0, len = bigArr.length; i < len; i++) {
        var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

        Array.from(bigArr).forEach(function(e, i) {
          e.textContent = arr[Math.round(Math.random()*(arr.length-1))];
        });
      };
    }
```

Comment: why not `querySelectorAll(‘selector section’);` and iterate over those elements?

Comment: bigArr is already an array. You should rather use Array.from on the Nodelist you get out of document.querySelectorAll, and then map over it, as I understand it.

Comment: @PhilippSander because the selector is very big like "document.querySelectorAll('.srow:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+6) .cell:nth-child(n+7):nth-child(-n+9)');" and it's easier to keep in variables I think.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a Node List but you are trying to modify it's `textContent` which does not exist. You might try `document.querySelector("selector section one")` or `e[0].textContent`

Comment: @Redu I need that 'document.querySelectorAll()' in order to return all elements of section, if I use 'document.querySelector' will return only the first element.

Comment: Then what  you receive at `Array.from(bigArr).forEach(e => ...` is a Node List you should iterate over `e` as well such as `for (var node of e) node.textContent = whatever`